# Does php file() put the array in RAM?

Tags: php, file, function, ram

Looking at the `file_get_contents` I see that documentation states it will load the file as string in memory, but will `file()` do that for the array it creates?

Does `file()` store the data in RAM?

Comment: What else could it do? Surely it won't save the array to disk.

Comment: Anything that is created uses up a memory block - variables, arrays, objects etc.

Comment: Yes, it does. [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/SplFileObject) does not, but also allows to iterate over lines.

Comment: @Damon That makes sense, I was thinking the same thing, but the script gets slower when using data from the end of the file, I guess I shouldn't let it do stuff so linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PHP stores strings, objects, arrays, etc. in memory unless explicitly stored to disk.

Here is a great test case about how much memory arrays really use: http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

From the article:

```
<?php
$startMemory = memory_get_usage();
$array = range(1, 100000);
echo memory_get_usage() - $startMemory, ' bytes';
```

> How much would you expect it to be? Simple, one integer is 8 bytes (on
>   a 64 bit unix machine and using the long type) and you got 100000
>   integers, so you obviously will need 800000 bytes. That’s something
>   like 0.76 MBs.
>
> Now try and run the above code. You can do it online if you want. This
>   gives me 14649024 bytes. Yes, you heard right, that’s 13.97 MB -
>   eightteen times more than we estimated.

Comment: This was enlightening really. Thanks.

Comment: When working with my file it returns `3568385048 bytes` on a 2GB test machine.